# Martin's Axiom and products of c.c.c. spaces

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing, infinitary-combinatorics

A topological space $X$ has the [c.c.c.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_chain_condition) if every family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$ is countable. Consider the following statement:

$(P)$ The product of two c.c.c. spaces is c.c.c.

It is known that that [Martin's Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_Axiom) $\mathrm{MA}(\omega_1)$ implies $(P)$. A reference is Kunen's *Set theory*, Chapter II.

**Question.** Does the converse also hold? If not, how can we force $(P) \wedge \neg \mathrm{MA}(\omega_1)$?

By the way, $(P)$ is equivalent to the statement that c.c.c. spaces are closed under *arbitrary* products, not just binary products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this question is open. See for example the paper '[Chain Conditions in Maximal Models](http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?fm168-1-3)' by Larson and Todorcevic where this and other related questions are discussed. In particular, this question is Question 2 in Section 10 (what you call $(P)$ they call $\mathcal{C}^2$, with the definition given in Section 4).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reference.